# Delete the "reference" meta tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There are [four questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) on main with the [reference](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) tag:

1. [Where can I find D4 dice that are truncated tetrahedrons?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/11462/6692)
2. [Where can I find a chart or diagram explaining Magic's turn structure?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/20861/6692)
3. [Where can I find the rules for 7 Wonders and its expansions?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/10938/6692)
4. [Where can I find the most reliable information on upcoming boardgame releases?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8798/6692)

The tag is clearly a meta tag. It doesn't describe what the questions are about. It basically says "The information contained within can be used as a reference." Well, everything on the entire main site could be used as a reference.

Should we get rid of this tag? I understand that the last question would need to be retagged. I propose something to do with board game releases. That's what the question is about.

Note that I did just retitle three of the four questions.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

We should get rid of the [reference](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) tag because it is a meta tag. Three of the four questions that use it simply do not need it. The last can be retagged with something more relevant (such as [releases](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/releases)).

Comment: This answer has a triggered ability: When this answer reaches +3, if no dissenting answer exists, the plan shall be carried out.